# Standard height from floor to ceiling?

Tags: floor, ceiling

Is there a standard height from floor to ceiling. I want to install some false ceiling (plaster board) ...

I seem to remember there was a standard but i don't remember it

Any help really appreciated

Comment: What's your current room height and where are you? I would think that your local building regulations would have something to say on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer,  If your community subscribes to the the national IRC building codes, then the minimum ceiling height is 7 feet for living spaces.  Some towns will allow less in basement rec rooms, but rarely is it more than the 7 foot min.

Answer (score 4):

In the US, it's right around 8' ... most lumber yards in the US will sell 2x4s just a bit under 8' so that when you build out a wall and add the top and sill, you'll end up pretty close to 8' high walls.

But that's a rough guide for a modest sized room.  Most people are okay with basements being a little shorter (so long as you don't get much below 7' tall, or it'll start to feel cramped, and might affect your resale ability to tall people).  Also, any lower than that, and you have problems fitting standard sized door openings.  In the US, 6'8" ... so it'd leave you with 4" for trimming it out.

If you have a really larger room, though, a lower ceiling is going to feel more restrictive ... on a small room it's cozy ... on a larger room, it's odd and unsettling.  (and I'm relatively short ... I don't know how it feels for people whose heads are scraping the ceiling)

Comment: It is annoying to try to move 4X8's around for sawing in a 7' basement.

Answer (score 0):

In the United States:

- Standard ceiling height is 8' 0".
- I greatly prefer a ceiling height of 8' 4".
- Many new homes have a higher ceiling height on the first floor.  9' 0", 9' 6", and 10' 0" are not unusual.
- Most building codes consider a "habitable room" (such as a living room or bedroom) to only have the square footage that has an average height (from nominal top of floor to nominal bottom of ceiling) of at least 7' 0".
- Standard doorways have a height of 6' 8".
- Building codes strongly encourage a minimum stairway height (from a plane tangent to the corners of the treads, vertically to the nominal ceiling surface) of 6' 8".

Answer (score 0):

Italian standard is 2,70m, and I find it almost claustrophobic, so I graterly prefer 3m.

PS: I've seen the post was quite old, but was only about US, So I added an answer for my country.